# Error in reasoning that $-\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}+x^{2}-x^{4}$ is essentially self-adjoint on $\mathcal{C}_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, mathematical-physics

According to Reed and Simon, Methods of Mathematical Physics II Section X.5 Example 1 (pg. 195), the operator
$$A:= -\Delta+x^{2}-x^{4}$$
is not essentially self-adjoint on $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, the space of $C^{\infty}$ functions with compact support. I am trying to understand the flaw in the reasoning of the following argument for showing that $A$ *is* essentially self-adjoint on $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.

Since $A$ is symmetric, $A$ is closable and we denote its closure by $\bar{A}: D(\bar{A})\rightarrow L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, where
$$D(\bar{A}) = \{f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}) : ((-\Delta+x^{2}-x^{4})f)_{dist} \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})\}$$
In words, $D(\bar{A})$ consists of all $L^{2}$ functions such that the distribution $Af$ is given by the integral action of a (unique) $L^{2}$ equivalence class.

To see that $\bar{A}:D(\bar{A}) \rightarrow L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ is self-adjoint, we argue as follows. Suppose $g\in D(\bar{A}^{*})$. If $f\in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})\subset D(\bar{A})$, then by definition of $D(\bar{A}^{*})$,
$$\langle{f,\bar{A}^{*}g}\rangle_{L^{2}} = \langle{\bar{A}f,g}\rangle_{L^{2}}=\langle{(-\Delta+x^{2}-x^{4})f,g}\rangle_{L^{2}}$$
$(-\Delta+x^{2}-x^{4}g)$ is a well-defined distribution in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$, and there by definition of differentiation and multiplication of distributions, we have that
$$\langle{(-\Delta+x^{2}-x^{4})f,g}\rangle_{L^{2}} = \langle{f,(-\Delta+x^{2}-x^{4})g}\rangle_{\mathcal{D}-\mathcal{D}'},$$
where $\langle{\cdot,\cdot}\rangle_{\mathcal{D}-\mathcal{D}'}$ denotes the duality pairing. Since the preceding holds for all $f\in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, we conclude that
$$\bar{A}^{*}g=(-\Delta +x^{2}-x^{4})g \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}).$$
Sincere $\bar{A}^{*}g\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, we have by definition of $D(\bar{A})$, that $\bar{A}^{*}g\in D(\bar{A})$.

Looking back to the preceding argument, I am guessing that the error in my reasoning is that
$$D(\bar{A})\neq \{f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}) : ((-\Delta+x^{2}-x^{4})f)_{dist} \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})\}$$
It seems clear that $D(\bar{A})$ is a subset of the set on the RHS, but it does not seem so obvious to me how to show the reverse inclusion.

Comment: With this argument you could prove that every symmetric operator is self-adjoint. To prove self-adjointness you need to show something more than that, see e.g. [Terry Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/the-spectral-theorem-and-its-converses-for-unbounded-symmetric-operators/) (which is largely based on the book by Reed and Simon you mentioned). Search "Examples of “expected consequences” include"

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: Thank you for your comment. Which step specifically  in my argument is incorrect. Reading through Tao's blog post has not clarified this matter for me. I am iffy about the identification of the domain of the closure of $A$, but I feel comfortable with the remainder of the argument.

Comment: Exercise 12 in Tao's blog is the relevant one here. To show your operator is not essentially self-adjoint you should disprove point (i). Notice that if you take the $-x^4$ term away, you are left with a positive operator, which is essentially self-adjoint because of point (ii).

Comment: Concerning domains. All symmetric operators satisfy $D(A)\subset D(\overline A)\subset D(A^\star)$. Essential self-adjointness is the statement that $D(A^\star)\subset D(\overline A)$, which is non-trivial, and which is missing from your reasoning here.

Comment: The closure $A^c$ of your operator is not necessarily the same as the operator $\overline{A}$ that you have defined. By assuming that it is, you have, in effect, assumed that $A$ is essentially selfadjoint.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: The latter part of the argument addresses the question of $D(\bar{A}^{*}) \subset D(\bar{A})$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts: Ah, I see. So am I correct, though, in my reasoning that the operator $\bar{A}$, which I have defined, is self-adjoint?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: Thanks, I am familiar with the criterion. My question is not how to prove this operator is not essentially self-adjoint, but rather what the specific error in the reasoning of the claimed proof is. It seems that DisintegratingByParts has addressed this.

Comment: The minimal operator $A_m$ is defined on $C_{c}^{\infty}$. The maximal operator $A_M$ is defined on your domain for $\overline{A}$. It is true that $A_M = A_m^*$, but that does not give selfadjointness or essential selfadjointness. The graphs of these two operators differ because $\mathcal{N}(A_M\pm iI) \ne \{0\}$, and the elements of these spaces give rise to boundary conditions at $\pm\infty$, which you can see by looking at $b_g(f)=(A_Mf,g)-(f,A_Mg)$, which is $0$ for all $f\in \mathcal{C}_{c}^{\infty}$ for a fixed $g\in \mathcal{D}(A_M)$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts: Thanks. I guess there is something still wrong in my basic understanding of the problem. I still do not see (maddeningly) why my distributional argument in my post does not show that $D(A_{M}^{*}) \subset D(A_{M})$, hence $D(A_{M}^{*})=D(A_{M})$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts: Ah, I think I see my flaw. I only checked that $D(A_{M}^{*}) \subset D(A_{M})$, but I did not actually verify that $A_{M}$ is symmetric (i.e. $\langle{A_{M}f,g}\rangle=\langle{f,A_{M}g}\rangle$ for $f,g in D(A_{M})$). Moving $A_{M}$ over to the other side would require approximate $g$ by test functions $g_{n}$, which I can't necessarily do because I don't know that $A_{M}g_{n}\rightarrow A_{M}g$ in $L^{2}$ ($D(A_{M})$ is larger than the domain of the closure of $A_{m}$). Or truncating the domain, using that $x^{2}f,x^{4}f$ are locally $L^{2}$. IBP, I pick up BCs.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The endpoint conditions are in one-to-one correspondence with the deficiency spaces $\mathcal{D}(A_M^2+I)=\mathcal{N}(A_M+iI)\oplus\mathcal{N}(A_M-iI)$. You either have two endpoint conditions at $-\infty$ or none, and the same is true at $+\infty$; there is a basis of real continuous endpoint functionals in $\mathcal{N}(A_M^2+I)$ because the equation is real. Non-selfadjointness is equivalent to requiring conditions at $\pm\infty$, which is why Quantum cannot allow this.